# How do I arrange LVP where they meet between hallway and room?

Tags: installation, vinyl

I want to install my panels parallel to the main long wall as you enter in at the entrance door, but in order to run parallel in the attached hallway, I would have to run them horizontal to the entrance door. Would it matter if I do not run parallel to the walls in the narrow hallway and go crossways or should I use a transition strip to change direction in the hallway from the living room?

Comment: You edited to make this about "luxury" vinyl plank. It's not remotely clear from the original that that is the product "panels" in question, so are you applying remote sensing or assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

There is common practice that says to run the planks parallel to the long wall.

That is not cast in stone.  You may run the planks as you wish.  There may be a trade off, such as more cuts, more waste, more time, more difficulties in the installation, but the choice is yours.

Comment: Exactly right. So many things in construction are taken as rules when they are just opinions. You run your floor however you like.

Comment: When the floor is wood, (which behaves anisotropically) there's a good reason for that practice. When it's plastic, (which behaves isotropically) not so much.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly an aesthetic question but to answer one practical aspect: If you are using the exact same product in two adjacent rooms, their floors are level and there is no door, you should avoid using a transition strip because the strip will draw attention and suggest you're hiding a problem.

If there is a door (not just a doorway, an actual door that closes) a transition strip won't look so bad, and a change of flooring won't look bad even if it's the same product.  If there is a step or the subfloors are not level between the two rooms, you'll *need* a transition so that gives you more freedom to choose flooring directions.

But you should have a compelling reason to add a strip *just* to change direction when otherwise the strip looks out of place.